# JApplet cannot find XML file as an InputStream

Tags: java, applet, inputstream

I am sorry for the dumb question I have been trying for a while to read some XML files in my applet without having to sign it. I know it is possible. I am just not sure where my mistake is. So far my Applet runs smoothly when invoked within eclipse, but when I try to put it on a server I get a null pointer on the XML files. I made the jar file with eclipse. All the XMLs are inside and I am sure I am referencing the right path. I tried all of the methods I found here, but I just cant get around that.

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("data" + 
                                        File.separator + "settings.xml");
Document settings = docBuilder.parse(in);
```

This is how I am trying to read the file now. The XML is stored in a folder named data, in the same package as MyClass.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I totaly overlooked this bit, because it was an application before it became an Applet. Now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.."data" + File.separator + "settings.xml"..
```

Don't use the file separator for a string the represents a relative URL! Use `/` always for URL refs. Also prefix it with another `/`, vis. `"/data/settings.xml"`.